# JPA Named Query showing error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to execute JPA named query on my entity, but it is showing syntax error. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with my named query?

```
@Repository
public interface CollegeRepository extends CrudRepository<CollegeEntity, Integer> {


    @Query("SELECT c FROM(SELECT *,(((acos(sin((:latitude * pi()/180)) * sin((latitude*pi()/180))+cos((:latitude * pi()/180)) * cos((latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((:longitude - longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM college) t WHERE distance <= 30")
    List<CollegeEntity> getCollegeByLocation(@Param("latitude") Double latitude, @Param("longitude") Double longitude, @Param("distance") Integer distance);    
}
```

This is error after executing above query.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 14 [SELECT c FROM(SELECT *,(((acos(sin((:latitude * pi()/180)) * sin((latitude*pi()/180))+cos((:latitude * pi()/180)) * cos((latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((:longitude - longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM college) t WHERE distance <= :distance]
```

When I execute below native query in MySQL terminal then working good.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM(SELECT *,(((acos(sin((0.0 * pi()/180)) * sin((latitude*pi()/180))+cos((0.0 * pi()/180)) * cos((latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((0.0 - longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM college) t WHERE distance <= 30;
Empty set (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: User has 2 queries posted and doesn't say which one they refer to, nor what the "syntax error" is. Also there is no JPA "named query" there. You have 2 SPRING DATA JPA queries

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question.

Comment: I have edited my question, Thanks for suggestion

Comment: so it isnt valid JPQL, as you have been told on the answer

Comment: Yes, it is not valid JPQL, you can see error, I have edited answer with error too.

Comment: Since JPQL has no such "sin", "acos", "pi", blah blah, then you'd have to use "FUNCTION('sin',...)" etc. But you can get all of that from any decent JPA reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your query is not a correct JPQL Syntax, because there are no  `acos`, `pi`, `sin`, `cod` functions in JPA, your query look like a native query, to solve your problem you have two options :

- **First option :** Convert your query to a correct JPQL syntax, you can follow the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html)
- **Second option :** use `nativeQuery = true` attribute `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT * FROM(...")`, note the `*` there are no alias `c` in your query.

You can use :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT *,"
        + "(((acos(sin((0.0 * pi()/180)) * sin((latitude*pi()/180)) + "
        + "cos((0.0 * pi()/180)) * cos((latitude*pi()/180)) * "
        + "cos(((0.0 - longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi()) * "
        + "60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM college) t WHERE distance <= 30;", 
        nativeQuery = true)
```

---

In your case, I strongly suggest the second option.

Comment: I used the second option, But there is error showing "Invalid MemberValuePair". Any suggestion?

Comment: @SagarYadav can you edit your question and add the full error, beside focus on one error per question please

Comment: I am accepting your answer. But, before that can you tell me what can be JPQL alternative? If the JPQL option is too difficult, can you describe why you strongly suggest the second option?

Comment: @SagarYadav i already mention that, because you are using some function not exist in JPQL, unless you go with other options like http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_func.htm